# Does C++ return 0 or NULL on failure?

Tags: c++, return

What's the value of return when a C++ program fails? I've read some articles on this but nothing explicit.

If it doesn't return 0, is there a way into making the program return 0 or NULL on failure? I've red something about std::nothrow but found no practical examples so far. Can anyone clarify this to me?

Comment: Do you mean the exit status of the program? If yes, why is it important that your program always returns `EXIT_SUCCESS`? If you're on Linux, you can just use it like this in a Makefile or Shellscript: `program || true`, which always is successful.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "return value", and if that's the program's exit code, 0 (not null, it's not a pointer) is usually a sign of _success_, not failure.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark: True, but that is almost always 0.

Comment: `std::nothrow` has nothing to so with what the program returns; it's used to make `new` return null on failure, rather than the default behaviour of throwing `std::bad_alloc`.

Answer (score 9):

The standard defines `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` error codes with obvious meanings. They can be passed to either `exit()` function or explicitly returned with `return` statement from the `main` function.  You can wrap the whole `main` function like

```
int main() try {
...
} catch(...) {
 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Your question is otherwise unclear.

Comment: You rightfully mention `EXIT_SUCCESS`, so why don't you use it in the sample program?

Comment: Good point, thanks. It's a deeply ingrained habit of mine to use 0 as successful. exit code.

Comment: try catch block dosn't work on some "microsoft specific" throws. but it works perfectly on user defined throws.

Comment: It also doesn't work if the program is terminated by a signal like `SIGTERM` or `SIGSEGV` or something like that, but I think it's still a good solution.

Comment: Thanks. That's my answer. I have no clue why my question was downvoted. I guess some people do that for a living.

Comment: @ThePlan you're lucky being downvoted, my similar question was closed :D

Comment: I'm aware that there are many platform-specific causes of failure, but since he mentioned std::nothrow, I assume that he's interested only in catching standard C++ exceptions. The most robust solution for any platform would be for the program to fork/reexecute itself, where child does main work, and parent waits for child termination and always returns EXIT_SUCCESS.

Comment: @ThePlan: It was probably downvoted because it was not clear what the question actually was about. Did you want to know the difference between `0` and `NULL`? Did you want to know what the exit code of a failing C++ program should be (hint: It's *NOT* `0`)? Also, there is not much sense in a solution like zvrba's one (although it is valid). Why do you need the exit status to indicate success, although the program failed? This indicates that the problem rather should be fixed in the calling program instead.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark: And most importantly, did he mixup "program" with "function", esp. since he also mentions `nothrow`? Is he trying to end the program when ANY function "fails"? [Whatever "failure" might mean for him.] Also, a program returns zero, a function may return zero or NULL. Anyway, I downvoted the question because it is imprecise, and as stated really doesn't make sense, so I had to use a crystal ball and guess what he was interested in.

Comment: Why catch an unhandled exception and return success? If an exception gets that far, it's a failure.

Comment: @GMan: I don't care about *why* (yes, it's a bad idea), I have just answered the *how*.

Answer (score 4):

NULL is just a macro for 0 as far as I know.

In stdlib.h:

```
/* Define NULL pointer value */

#ifndef NULL
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define NULL 0
#else
#define NULL ((void *)0)
#endif
#endif
```

The [source](http://www.c-plusplus.de/forum/39480) (German) where I copied this from also states that using NULL is not recommended by Stroustrup.

Comment: Thanks for editing Sathya. I was struggling if I put the line into the block or out, but seperating it is a good trick :D

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear. The value that you return from `main` is precisely the value that you pass to the `return` statement in `main`. Nothing else can be said about that.

Now, what question should you really be asking? There are two aspects: One is the C++ side, and the other is the host side (i.e. the operating system).

You don't have any control over how any given operating system handles error conditions of programs that it launches. The only thing that the C++ standard guarantees are this:

- If your `main` returns `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, or not at all, then the program ends in a manner that signals success; and
- if your `main` returns `EXIT_FAILURE`, then the program ends in a manner that signals failure.

The actual return values of your program depend entirely on the platform, i.e. the operating system and the runtime environment.

For example, on Linux success is signalled via the value 0 and failure via a non-zero value, so a C or C++ program can be executed by simply returning the value of `main()` back to the OS (and defining `EXIT_SUCCESS` as `0`). Other platforms may choose different semantics!

Answer (score 0):

There is commonly assumed that a program returns 0 when it succeeds, and non-zero value otherwise.

You set the return value by returning from main function:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  return 0; // Finish with success
}
```

or by passing the return code to the `exit(int)` function.

Also it is worth noting, that `NULL` is defined precisely as `(void*)0` and is used when talking about pointers, not integers. If you don't understand what does it mean, read a decent C tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

NULL is macro and it is same sa 0, it's defined like so:

```
#define NULL 0
```

when program fails it return 1 by default signaling the operating system that program failed.
if return value is grater than 1 then this is done by programer who wroted that program.

if program executes sucessefuly it always retun's 0.
you should never retun value other than 0 on program failure cos you will not know if it failed or not.

also if return value is lower thatn 0 that means fail as well.
so only sucess value is 0 or NULL which is same.

Answer (score -1):

Successful runs usually have error code `0`, anything other than `0` indicates some sort of error.

```
Error code                     Value              Description
ERROR_SUCCESS                    0            The action completed successfully.
ERROR_INVALID_DATA               13           The data is invalid.
ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER          87           One of the parameters was invalid.
```

More :  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368542(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: "These error codes are returned by the Windows Installer functions". Wrong domain.